# What is the difference between tibble and data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames Data_row and Data_row1.
I do some certain operations on Data_row to reach Data_row1.

When I check for the class of each I get the following output:

```
> class(Data_row)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> class(Data_row1)
[1] "data.frame"
```

I just want to know the difference between the two types.

Comment: Certain functions are available and optimised for them in the tidyverse library. Other than that it is just a class.

Comment: You can try this link: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html

Comment: You question is answered by the documentation. See `help("tbl_df")`.